# How can I create oversample(same in caffe lib) in keras

Tags: python, keras, caffe, pycaffe

In caffe has Oversample method, that crop the images into the four corners, center and pass though in the network classifier.

This is an oversample method code in caffe. [https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/io.py]

I would like to create oversample in Keras library follow the oversample method in caffe.

Now, I have only 1 approach that is a create the generator method and apply to the predict_generator method in keras library. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I don't know why.

Please anyone suggest me.